# Программа выводит пустоту. Помогите найти проблему

Tags: c

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file = fopen("1.txt", "r"); // Открываем файл для чтения
    
    if (file == NULL) { // Проверяем успешность открытия файла
        printf("Ошибка открытия файла\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    int rows = 0, cols = 0;
    int **array = NULL;
    
    // Считываем количество строк и столбцов из файла
    while (!feof(file)) {
        int c = fgetc(file);
        if (c == ' ') {
            cols++;
        } else if (c == '\n') {
            rows++;
        }
    }
    
    // Перемещаем указатель в начало файла
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    
    // Выделяем память для массива
    array = (int **)malloc(rows * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        array[i] = (int *)malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
    }
    
    // Читаем массив из файла
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    fclose(file); // Закрываем файл
    
    // Находим среднее арифметическое каждого столбца
    float *averages = (float *)malloc(cols * sizeof(float));
    
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        int sum = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            sum += array[i][j];
        }
        
        averages[j] = (float)sum / rows;
    }
    
    // Удаляем столбцы с элементами равными среднему арифметическому
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        int removeColumn = 1;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            if (array[i][j] == averages[j]) {
                removeColumn = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (removeColumn) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for (int k = j; k < cols - 1; k++) {
                    array[i][k] = array[i][k + 1];
                }
            }
            
            cols--;
            j--;
        }
    }
    
    // Выводим массив после удаления столбцов
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        
       printf("\n"); 
    }
    
    // Освобождаем память, выделенную для массива
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
    
    free(averages);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А вы как-то забыли написать, что **должна** делать эта программа. Вдруг ничего? :) Для начала, у вас очень странный способ считать количество столбцов...

Comment: У вас наоборот **не удаляются** только столбцы, где есть элементы, равные среднему арифметическому. А поскольку средние арифметические у вас типа `float`, а сами массивы типа `int`, то, хоть я и плохо помню `C`, но, думаю, таких совпадений найдено не будет. `float` имеет ограниченную точность, там всё плохо с прямым сравнением.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, понял!